# Clicking on home screen Widget

Tags: android, widget

The home screen widget of my app looks like this.

[image: home screen]

I want to click in a row item and launch the MainActivity of my app. I am using the following code but nothing happens.

```
public class GridWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new 
NewsListRemoteVieFactory(this.getApplicationContext());
}
}

class NewsListRemoteVieFactory implements 
RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory{

    public  static ArrayList<News> newsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context mContext;

    public NewsListRemoteVieFactory(Context applicationContext) {

        this.mContext = applicationContext;

    }


    private void readNews(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = prefs.getString("news", "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>(){}.getType();
        newsArrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        readNews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        readNews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(newsArrayList == null){
            return 0;
        }
        return newsArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_grid_view_item);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_grid_view_item, "\u2022 " + newsArrayList.get(position).getTitle()
                + "\n" + String.valueOf(newsArrayList.get(position).getDescription()));



        Bundle selectedNewsBundle = new Bundle();
        selectedNewsBundle.putParcelableArrayList("news",newsArrayList);

        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_grid_view_item, fillInIntent);


        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, fillInIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_grid_view_item, pendingIntent);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_grid_view_item, pendingIntent);

        return views;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call `setPendingIntentTemplate()` on the Widget's main `RemoteViews` with the `GridView` ID, and the base `PendingIntent`? Also, you should remove the `setOnClickPendingIntent()` call you have in `getViewAt()`.

Comment: @Mike M. Oops! No it's fixed. Thanks.